# How do I send multiple objects to .ejs file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to pass a query from MySQL to .ejs file, and send object at the same time.

In the following code, I am trying to send `rows` and `{ pageTitle: "Edit Agents" }` to `edit_agents` page

```
Router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query("select * from agent", (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("edit_agents", rows);
      res.render("edit_agents", { pageTitle: "Edit Agents" });
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
});
```

Just to let you know, I am using NodeJs (express framework) with ejs views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query("select * from agent", (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("edit_agents", { data: rows,pageTitle: "Edit Agents" });
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I am quite new in NodeJs. It's pretty simple, thanks a lot its work